# Why a and b are not swapped in this code?

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union
{
    unsigned u;
    double d;
} a,b;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a, b:");
    scanf("%lf %lf",&a.d,&b.d);
    if(a.d>b.d)
    {
        a.u^=b.u^=a.u^=b.u;
    }
    printf("a=%g, b=%g\n",a.d,b.d);
    return 0;
}
```

The `a.u^=b.u^=a.u^=b.u;` statement should have swapped `a` and `b` if `a>b`, but it seems that whatever I enter, the output will always be exactly my input.

Comment: I just have to say that if readability and maintainability are of any value to you you should find a simpler way to accomplish this task.  Not an answer I know but...

Comment: Think about how unions work, and consider sizeof(a.u) vs sizeof(a.d).

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that writing to `a.d` then reading from `a.u` is undefined behaviour. Do you have optimizations on?

Comment: @keithmo I get you, thanks!

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure. As a newbie programmer, I just open code::blocks, type my code, then press F9. I didn't touch anything about the compiler.

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of this code is?

Comment: @immibis union aliasing is not UB unless a trap representation is formed, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified)

Comment: @M.M To swap two double floats, a and b, when necessary, to ensure that a<=b without using a third variable.

Answer (score 2):

`a.u^=b.u^=a.u^=b.u;` causes undefined behaviour by writing to `a.u` twice without a sequence point. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133428/why-does-xor-swap-with-integers-trigger-a-warning) for discussion of this code.

You could write:

```
unsigned tmp;
tmp = a.u;
a.u = b.u;
b.u = tmp;
```

which will swap `a.u` and `b.u`.  However this may not achieve the goal of swapping the two doubles, if `double` is a larger type than `unsigned` on your system (a common scenario).

Comment: The whole point of his using the union is so that he can use the XOR swap instead of a temporary variable.

Comment: @Barmar bad luck for him then

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that `double` is 64 bits, while `unsigned` is only 32 bits. When you swap the `unsigned` members of the unions, you're only getting half of the `doubles`.

If you change `d` to `float`, or change `u` to `unsigned long long`, it will probably work, since they're likely to be the same size.

You're also causing UB by writing to the variables twice without a sequence point. The proper way to write the XOR swap is with multiple statements.

```
b.u ^= a.u;
a.u ^= b.u;
b.u ^= a.u;
```

For more about why not to use XOR for swapping, see [Why don't people use xor swaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535461/why-dont-people-use-xor-swaps)

Comment: @M.M Unspecified or implementation-dependent, then?

Comment: @M.M But aren't there issues due to size and alignment? If you read a larger member than you wrote, you're accessing uninitialized memory.

Comment: OK, I've removed any mention of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In usual environment, memory size of datatype 'unsigned' and 'double' are different.
That is why variables are not look like changed.

And you cannot using XOR swap on floating point variable.
because they are represented totally different in memory.

Comment: You can if they're the same size.  The problem is that they're probably not.